# Reliable point spatial data of cities of New Zealand

Tags: data-request, geospatial, releasing-data

Can anyone refer to the reliable and freely available point location spatial data source of the cities of New Zealand?

N.B. I used several data sources but found all of them are not accurate e.g. [this](http://www.tageo.com/index-e-nz-cities-NZ.htm) and [this](http://www.mapsofworld.com/lat_long/newzealand-lat-long.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could set up an account with [Land Information New Zealand--LINZ Data Service](https://data.linz.govt.nz/) 
Once you log in, hit browse data. 
The select Gazetteer option. That should show you three options. Select 
NZ Place Names (NZGB) and the click on the plus sign. This will select all values from the dataset.
Then from the top right hand corner, click download.
Select csv file option to down load.
Open in your spreadsheet application.
Look for the feat_type column. Sort based on that column. Look for suburb, city, town, village. I would double check each type of item in that column to see if there is any more city/town like names.

Comment: I used that shapefile format but duplicates are really throw me into dilemma. Again i used a geocoder service to locate cities in NZ which differ from this gaetteer.

Comment: Duplicates you can remove through your spreadsheet application--sort by lat/long

Comment: I see but location is not correct for some cities i checked!

Answer (score 1):

The [New Zealand Gazetteer of place names](https://www.linz.govt.nz/regulatory/place-names/find-place-name/new-zealand-gazetteer-place-names) provides a direct link to download [gaz.csv](https://gazetteer.linz.govt.nz/gaz.csv)

It seems this file is updated on a regular basis, and currently contains 38 attributes on over 52k features. To find cities, you will need to filter `feat_type` on either *Town* or *City*.